# Is create and update treated as separate "External Inputs" for function point estimation?

Tags: function-points

I've an ILF which needs to be maintained through the UI. There are create and update screens to create a new entity and update an existing entity respectively. Are these considered as two separate "External Inputs" for function point sizing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are. They are different processes and both are external inputs.

In the first case, you input the data to create an entity. In the second case, you have to read and display the data before modifying them.
So, the set of processing logic to complete the elementary process is different in both cases.